# SASS not updating my Ionic app styles

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, sass

I've got an Ionic 3 app which tries to use some .scss files to give the app a better look, but... no style is being applied. In my components, which have a .ts, a .html and a .scss file, I just try to use classes from my .scss in my .html, but the styling changes will just not render.

So well, I just made a little experiment: tried to create a css class called "testclass123" that sets the color of a text to "green", and apply it to a

.

The style won't render, but the compilation phase correctly puts the styling rules in the main.css file that is used in the served app:

[image]

As you can see, my class is there. But, why isn't it working at all?

Thank you!

Comment: try .testclass123 { color: green !important}

Comment: @Gautam Oh, you're right. I used to do this but I had totally forgotten that you always need to put the !important for changing font colors in Ionic... many thanks! Why don't you put it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use !important on your color property

```
.testclass123 { color: green !important}
```